# i want to create dashboard component from tabular report

Tags: community, reporting, dashboard

i have following fields i want to create tabular report and then add to dashboard

```
No. Field Label Field Type

1 Address Text Area (Long)
2 Branch Picklist (Values : Mechanical , Computer , IT ,Civil )
3 Contact Lookup(Contact)
4 Phone No Phone (Must be Unique)
5 Email Email
6 Enrollment Text (20)
7 Reviewer Lookup(User)
```

i know i have to set row limit and change dashboard settings but when i go to dashboard settings i see this

[image]

please help me this is the requirement i cannot change the report type

i think it is not possible to make report with this available data what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabular reports cannot be shown as a dashboard component. You can only display summary and matrix reports.